# Covariance Matrix vs. Volatility Matrix

Tags: modeling

Consider a general multidimensional market model in which each of $m$ stocks is driven by $d$ Brownian motions (as in Shreve II, p. 226), viz.
$$
dS_i/S_i = \alpha_i dt + \sum_{j=1}^d \sigma_{ij}dW_j, \qquad i=1,\ldots,m,
$$
where each $W_j$ is independent of the others.  We could write this as a vector equation as
$$
 dS/S = \alpha dt + A dW
$$
where $S = (S_1,\ldots,S_m)^T$, $\alpha = (\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_m)^T$, $dW = (dW_1,\ldots,dW_m)^T$ and
$$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_{11} & \ldots & \sigma_{1d} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \\
\sigma_{m1} & \ldots & \sigma_{md}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
I've seen $A$ called the "volatility matrix," for obvious reasons.

On the other hand, I've also seen (similar to eqn (1) [in this article](http://www.wilmott.com/pdfs/120201_rainbow.pdf)) a multidimensional market model posed in matrix-vector form as
$$
dS/S = \alpha dt + B dW,
$$
where again each component of $W$ is independent of the rest.  The difference is the matrix $B$ is called the "square root of the covariance matrix $\Sigma$" in the article above, and they state that it is "...typical to take $B$ to be the Cholesky decomposition matrix of $\Sigma$," i.e., $BB^T = \Sigma$ where $B$ is lower triangular.  Note here that the authors implicitly assume $m=d$ in the notation above.

**First question:** I assume by "covariance matrix" we mean $\Sigma_{i,j} = Cov(R_i, R_j)$ where $R_i = \log\left(S_i(t) / S_i(0)\right)$ are the log returns.  Is this correct?  If so, there seems to be a factor of $t$ missing somewhere between the two model statements.  As a concrete example, let $m=d=2$ an consider *any* square root of the matrix $\Sigma$ (not necessarily a lower triangular one).  Then in the first model
$$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_{11} & \sigma_{12} \\
\sigma_{21} & \sigma_{22}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and in the second
$$
\Sigma = 
\begin{pmatrix}
Var(R_1) & Cov(R_1,R_2) \\
Cov(R_2,R_1) & Var(R_2)
\end{pmatrix}
= t
\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_{11}^2 + \sigma_{12}^2 & \sigma_{11}\sigma_{21} + \sigma_{12}\sigma_{22} \\
\sigma_{11}\sigma_{21} + \sigma_{12}\sigma_{22} & \sigma_{21}^2 + \sigma_{22}^2
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
If the two model statements are consistent, then I would expect $AA^T = \Sigma$, but in fact $AA^T = \frac{1}{t}\Sigma$.  So, by "covariance matrix" do we really mean $\Sigma_{ij} = \frac{1}{t}Cov(R_i,R_j)$?

**Second question:**  In the example above, $A$ was indeed a square root of the matrix $\Sigma$ where $\Sigma_{ij} = \frac{1}{t}Cov(R_i,R_j)$, and this seemed like the obvious choice for $A$ (at least to me).  But the authors of the article state $A$ could be taken to be lower triangular, which means stock $i$ is driven by only $i$ Brownian motions.  This seems like an extra restriction on the general model, where each stock is driven by some linear combination of *all* the Brownian motions.  So, is taking the "volatility" matrix to be lower triangular an extra restriction?

Answer (score 2):

1) People usually consider an instantaneous covariance while you are considering a integrated covariance. In a model 
$$
  dS_t = S_t \cdot (\alpha(t)dt + A(t)dW_t) 
$$
the integrated covariance of log-returns is simply the integral over time of the instantaneous covariance: 
$$
  Cov(R_i(t),R_j(t)) = (i,j)\textrm{-coeff. of} \int_0^t \underbrace  {A(s)A(s)^\top}_{\Sigma_{ij}(s)} ds
$$

2) This is not a restriction since the law of the process is the same (this is  just a change of coordinates of the driving brownian motion). From a modelling point of view, volatility (or correlation) is not what matters because it is never observed. Only (co)variance is.

Comment: okay, I think 1) makes sense.  Would you mind elaborating on 2), though?  Or, do you know a good source explaining this change of coordinates?  I'm also very interested in why covariance is considered "observed" but volatility is not.  Wouldn't we have to *compute* (really, approximate) both of them *from* the observed data?  E.g. $Var(R_i(t)) \approx \frac{1}{N-1}\sum_{j=1}^N (R_i(t_j) - \hat{\mu})^2$?

Comment: 2) first question is an exercise you should work out yourself. Second point is a consequence: you are estimating integrated variance and this estimator only depends on the variance on the $R_i$'s not on their volatility which is not canonically defined.

Comment: In the Gaussian case (i.e the drif and vol parameters are deterministic), it is easy to prove that the log-returns form a gaussian process whose law is characterized by its mean and covariance function.

Comment: Thanks again, but I'm still having a bit of trouble with the change of coordinates idea. Are you saying I should work out the transformation $AdW \mapsto BAdW$?  I.e., which is the "original" and "changed" coordinates?  Also, when you say the law of the process is the same, are you just saying each stock at a given time is lognormally distributed?  Then, under this change of coordinates, they still are, but with different volatilities?

Comment: What I am saying is that if you set $V = B^{-1}A$ (assuming B invertible for simplicity) then $VdW$ is again a Brownian motion. So you go from one model to the other by replacing a Brownian motion by another so you do not change the law of the stochastic process.

Comment: By law of the stochastic process, I mean the probabiliy measure on the space $C^0(\mathbb{R}_+,\mathbb{R}^d)$ or equivalently all the finite dimensional probabilities $Q(S_{t_1}\in A_1,\ldots,S_{t_n}\in A_n)$ for $A_i$ Borel sets of $\mathbb{R}^d)$. This is much stronger than having lognomal marginal distributions.